# Remove a MongoDB Document by ObjectId with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm new to both PHP and MongoDB.  I'd like to remove a MongoDB document using it's ObjectId, but can't seem to get it working.

Here is how the object gets added.  Because I do not specify the id, Mongo generates one for me.

```
public static function addUserPet($userPet) {
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->petfinder;
    $collection = $db->userpets;
    $collection->insert($userPet);
    echo json_encode($userPet);
}
```

And here is where I attempt to update the object.  I don't understand how to access the document using the ObjectId.

```
public static function deleteUserPet($userPet)
{
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->petfinder;
    $collection = $db->userpets;

    $criteria = ???

    $collection->remove($criteria, true);
}
```

What should $criteria be?

Note:  Here is the object being passed in.
[image: $userPet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get the collection and then fetch the document from a specific collection.
Have a look here please:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php

Regarding criteria:

```
array('_id' => new MongoId('47cc67093475061e3d9536d2')
```

Comment: Yeah this is what's hanging me up.  Where are we getting this '47cc..' from and why are we creating a new MongoId?  I just want to reference an existing document by it's ObjectId and make changes to it (or remove it).  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This id should come in the URL as a parameter if it's a crud or something like that. When you render the list on the frontend side you create a link like url?id=mongodbid. Or you should have a list of fetched objects by the other parameters like the name for example. Actually the same schema as with relational database.